# How can I plot several (21, 166) shaped arrays to the same plot?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have data files that I reshape into (21,166) numpy arrays and plot by looping through each row creating bands. This is then plotted against a k value with 166 elements, of course.

```
data = np.loadtxt('/some/user/directory/file.gnu')
k = np.unique(data[:, 0])  
bands = np.reshape(data[:,1],(21,166))

for band in range(len(bands)):
    ax.plot(k,bands[band,:], linewidth=1, alpha=1, color='k')
```

However, now I have several data files with several bands files, while k remains the same for all:

```
data1 = np.loadtxt('/some/user/directory/file1.gnu')
data2 = np.loadtxt('/some/user/directory/file2.gnu')
.
.
.
.

bands1 = np.reshape(data1[:,1],(21,166))
bands2 = np.reshape(data2[:,1],(21,166))
.
.
.
.
```

I need to plot each of these files together with everything overlayed together and I have been able to successfully get this to work, but in what feels like a very inefficient manner.

```
for band in range(len(bands1)) and range(len(bands2)) and range(len(bands3)) and.... :
    ax.plot(k,bands1[band,:],linewidth=1, alpha=1, color='g',linestyle = '--')
    ax.plot(k,bands2[band,:],linewidth=1.5, alpha=1, color='y')
    ax.plot(k,bands3[band,:],linewidth= 2, alpha=1, color='r',linestyle = 'dashed')
    . 
    . 
    .
```

I am wondering if anyone out there has any suggestions to make this a bit neater and prevent having to individually reference each bands array, because I have accumulated quite a few separate files for plotting together.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A few clarification questions: 1. What do you mean by "band" (do you mean curve)? 2. Is there a pattern for curve format (e.g., color, linewidth, linestyle, etc.) within each data file or across data files?

Comment: Also, if you can provide a few dummy data files and an example of the expected output plot, that would be extremely helpful.